# Como gerar números randômicos iniciando por 00000 até 99999 sem repetição usando apenas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Como gerar números randômicos iniciando por 00000 até 99999 sem repetição usando apenas MySQL, os números não podem iniciar em 000, alguém tem ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Pesquise sobre a função `rand()`. Com ela você já consegue ter uma ideia de como fazer.

Comment: Qual o limite? Quantos números aleatórios?

Comment: Como assim, não pode começar em 000? Números nunca começam com 0. O que você quer é de 100 pra frente então?

Comment: acho que ele queria dizer maior que 100 (00100)

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo é, eu pensei uma coisa e escrevi outra, eu acho que é isto, mas quero que ele confirme, está esquisito.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680025/how-to-generate-random-number-without-repeat-in-database-using-php/40549385#40549385 alterando `WHERE my_number IS NOT NULL)` para `WHERE my_number >100)`

Comment: É pra usar com INSERT ou com SELECT?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Bruno. Eu acho que vc pode usar isso aqui:

```
select FLOOR(RAND() * 99999)
```

Ou melhor:

```
BEGIN


DECLARE valorRand bigint;
        set valorRand = select FLOOR(RAND() * 99999);
        if exists (select * from tabela where coluna = valorRand) then
            call meuRandon();
        end if

        return valorRand;
```

ai tem que ver quantas vezes isso pode se repetir.

Comment: Testa no seu mySQL

Comment: E como você garante que isto não terá repetição?

Comment: @Maniero não garante. rsrsrs

Comment: @cpll obrigado pela força, mas não pode haver repetições.

Comment: @Bruno Richart, é preciso moldar melhor a ideia sobre as suas regras e necessidades, mas tentei fazer com que a função, só retorne um valor quando ele ainda não existir. Fiz recursivo, mas a ideia pode ser melhora e feita em funções.

Comment: @cpll sim verdade, mas ajudou muito já consegui, muito obrigado.